# Run .bat file using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I have a batch file, which I use to load some pre-build binaries to control my device.
It's command is:

```
cd build
java -classpath .;..\Library\mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x86\RXTXcomm.jar -
Djava.library.path=..\Library\mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x86 tabotSample/Good1
pause
```

Now, I want to run the batch file using Python, and I tried  `os.system(batch,bat)`, and I tried using Popen

`import os
  from subprocess import Popen
  os.popen("cd TAbot")
  r=os.popen("hello.bat")`

However, the python console(Anaconda python 2.7) seems like executed the code, but returns nothing, and nothing happens.
I want to run this batch file from python, please help me.
by the way, I tried popen for another batch file like,
`echo Hello` but nothing happens.

Comment: As is, `cd build` won't work in general. To depend on the working directory to find resources relative to a script is a mistake. Make it relative to the directory of the batch file itself, instead of depending on the working directory. For example,  if the "build" directory is in the same directory as the batch file, you can use `cd /d "%~dp0build"`, where the batch filename is the `%0` parameter, and we're getting the [d]rive and base [p]ath as `%~dp0`.

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know why every time I use popen to run .bat file nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess

def run_batch_file(file_path):
    Popen(file_path,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

run_batch_file('file_name.bat')
```

**file_name.bat**

```
echo .bat file running from python
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat"], shell=False)
```

**test.bat**

```
copy "C:\temp\test.txt" "C:\temp\test2.txt"
```

Comment: It seems that batch file is working, however it need to choose Y/N, how do I input that? or pre input this key?

Comment: You can pass parameters for example subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat", "Y"] 
 or subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat", "N"]. In the bat file you have access to this parameters with %0, %1, ... . [http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)

Comment: I tried  subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat", "Y"] but, it didn't work. Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: I run xcopy "C:\temp\test.txt" "C:\temp\test2.txt" on cmd, and it asked me Y/N/A , it will be copied when I time Y or A. I want to do all the process by python. When I run subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat", "Y"]  in python, the kernel just stacked.

Comment: sorry my fault xcopy needs user interaction the example is not working correctly. try copy "C:\temp\test.txt" "C:\temp\test2.txt" and subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\test.bat"])

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Is that possible to pass my interaction choice by python code? My batch file has a pause command after running, so Can I, It's like  pre input the key?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work like this:

**batch.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("test.bat", cwd=r"C:\path\to\batch\folder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

**test.bat**

```
echo Hello World!
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here many guys suggested very useful solutions, but I want to point the importance of where is the program located. 
(Bat file is usually made for automation task to reduce time and this has high probability to work some task related path)

```
import subprocess

os.chdir("YOUR TARGET PATH")

exit_code = subprocess.call(FILEPATH)# FILEPATH is from the standpoint on YOUR TARGET PATH
```